# jquery smooth effect

Tags: jquery, effect, smoothing

I want to make something similar **[with this](http://s3.envato.com/files/1522522/index.html#/PORTFOLIO/image/img_3)**

When you click on "description" text appears.
I want to create this effect with jQuery, how can I make this?

Comment: Why not give it a shot first and then ask if you run into a problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a fadeToggle() ?

```
<a href="#" id="appear">Clicky</a>
    <p class="textTo" style="display: none;">Hello World!</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#appear").click(function() {
   $(".textTo").fadeToggle();
});
</script>
```

check out the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vfcp4/

and the api:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

the api shows a bit more.

for example there are some parameters to pass controlling animation speed, type, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) function in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<div id="description"> Description (click here to show) </div>
<div id="textToShow" style="display:none"> Now I'm visible ! </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#description").click(function(){
    $("#textToShow").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

You can use an image or any element to be shown.
Hope this helps. Cheers